# How to find a backwards merge in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

My company has release branches. Changes must be created in their own branch before being merged back to the release branch. A typical workflow might look like this:

```
    A---F----------M------ V.1
     \ / \        /           
      E   H------L
```

Changes were added in E, H, and L before being merged back to the release V.1 branch.

If we're working on V.2 at the same time, then any changes to V.1 must also be "merged forward" to V.2:

```
          C--D                
         /    \               
        B---G--J---K---N-- V.2
       /   / \    /   /       
      /   /   I--'   /        
     /   /          /         
    A---F----------M------ V.1
     \ / \        /           
      E   H------L
```

This ensures that any bugfixes that are applied to V.1 are carried forward into V.2.

Once in a while, a developer will accidentally merge to the wrong release branch. Let's say that commit 'I' which was branched from V.2 had instead been merged backwards into V.1:

```
          C--D                
         /    \               
        B---G--J-------N-- V.2
       /   / \        /       
      /   /   I      /        
     /   /     \    /         
    A---F-------K--M------ V.1
     \ / \        /           
      E   H------L
```

In this case we call K a "backwards merge". It causes all of the new features from V.2 to get merged into V.1, which is very bad.

When this happens we try to find the backwards merge K so that we can revert the changes. Unfortunately, with several hundred commits per day it can be very difficult to find K by inspecting the graph visually.

How can we find the backwards merge K programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this idea of a "backwards merge" is not something git knows anything about, you'll need to do some custom scripting.  (The closest thing I can think of to really helping here is `git bisect` - but it won't quite work, because it thinks it's looking for the individual commit that introduced some behavior, whereas you want to find where some behavior(s) got merged into a particular branch.)

So...

The first thin you need is a way to test that a commit contains changes from `v2`.  You could check out the earliest `v2` commit (`B` in your example graph) and create a tag there

```
git tag v2-root
```

Then you can check a commit to see if `v2-root` is "reachable"; there are several ways, but the most direct is probably

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor v2-root <some-commit>
```

Next you need a list of commits to test.  You can use `git rev-list`.  Under normal circumstances you could use

```
git rev-list --first-parent v1.0
```

This assumes that for every merge added to the release branch, the first parent is the prior commit of the release branch, which is normally true.  There are ways to create merges where this is not true.  (The simplest is to merge `V1.0` *into* another branch, then fast-forward `V1.0` onto the merge.)

If you're worried about things like that happening, then you'd have to omit the `--first-parent` option, and then your script needs a way to sort out the branch topology.  For now I'll assume that's not necessary.

So now you just need a script to work its way down the commit list, running the test (`git merge-base ...`) on each commit, until it finds one where the test returns false.  If the first (most recent) commit returns false, then there is no backward merge; otherwise, the last commit to return true is the backward merge.